# Mysql 5.7 - how to execute multiple subqueries that need the result of the previous subquery?

Tags: mysql, linux, subquery, left-join

Hoping someone may be able to assist me with what I believe is a subquery issue - that I'm unable to resolve.

I have a table that includes user referral information, referrals can be 3 tiers. For example.

Jim referred Steve

Ryan referred Jim

Stephanie referred Ryan

Mark referred Stephanie

What I'm trying to do as part of a larger query is retrieve the list of referrers for the user 'steve'
So ideally the query comes back with "

- Jim
- Ryan
- Stephanie
- Mark

To give you an idea of the 'user_referrals' table, if Steve was userid 6211

--

```
mysql> select * from user_referrals where referee = '6211';
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
| id   | referrer | referee | created                    | modified                   | isActualReferrer | deleted | version |
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
| 4934 |     6155 |    6211 | 2021-02-28 04:22:35.798832 | 2021-02-28 04:22:35.798832 |                1 | NULL    |       1 |
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select* from user_referrals where referee = '6155';
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
| id   | referrer | referee | created                    | modified                   | isActualReferrer | deleted | version |
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
| 4881 |     5757 |    6155 | 2021-02-25 17:44:42.103963 | 2021-02-25 17:44:42.103963 |                1 | NULL    |       1 |
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user_referrals where referee = '5757';
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
| id   | referrer | referee | created                    | modified                   | isActualReferrer | deleted | version |
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
| 4589 |       29 |    5757 | 2020-12-30 05:02:23.831882 | 2020-12-30 05:02:23.831882 |                1 | NULL    |       1 |
+------+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user_referrals where referee = '29';
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
| id | referrer | referee | created                    | modified                   | isActualReferrer | deleted | version |
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
|  7 |       24 |      29 | 2019-02-02 00:22:12.000000 | 2019-02-02 00:22:12.000000 |                1 | NULL    |       1 |
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The sub query portion of the main query looks like this

```
    LEFT JOIN
    
    ( select u1.referrer from user_referrals as u1 ) as u ON (u.id = u.referrer)
    
    LEFT JOIN
    
    ( select u1.referrer from user_referrals as u1 ) as u3 ON (u3.referrer = (
    select u2.referrer from user_referrals as u2 WHERE u.referrer = u2.referee)
    )
```

I don't think this is the best way to approach it, with the above in the main query, I've got the results as follows so far :

Sample query

```
select distinct(u.id),u.created,u.first_name,p.amount,u.referrer,u3.referrer from users as u
    LEFT JOIN
    ( Select p1.* FROM paymentledger as p1 LEFT JOIN paymentledger as p2 ON p1.userID = p2.userID AND p1.createdAt > p2.createdAt WHERE p2.userID IS NULL) as p ON (u.id = p.userID)
    LEFT JOIN
    
    ( select u1.referrer from user_referrals as u1 ) as u ON (u.id = u.referrer)
    
    LEFT JOIN
    
    ( select u1.referrer from user_referrals as u1 ) as u3 ON (u3.referrer = (
    select u2.referrer from user_referrals as u2 WHERE u.referrer = u2.referee)
    )
    WHERE u.created LIKE '2021-02-28%';
```

Sample output

```
+------+----------------------------+------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| id   | created                    | first_name       | amount | referrer | referrer |
+------+----------------------------+------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| 6202 | 2021-02-28 00:00:12.903938 | Brian            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6204 | 2021-02-28 00:44:52.317175 | Katie            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6205 | 2021-02-28 01:28:14.379496 | Stephanie        | 159.00 |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6206 | 2021-02-28 01:32:45.655260 | Christina        |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6207 | 2021-02-28 01:54:22.954110 | R                |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6208 | 2021-02-28 02:45:01.010985 | Lillie           |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6209 | 2021-02-28 02:53:10.819064 | Deborah          |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6210 | 2021-02-28 04:05:24.937563 | Danielle         |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6211 | 2021-02-28 04:22:35.103951 | Linda            | 159.00 |     6211 |     6155 |
| 6212 | 2021-02-28 04:32:53.045521 | Kathy            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6213 | 2021-02-28 05:05:17.063022 | malekmuneerah786 |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6214 | 2021-02-28 07:47:12.725790 | James            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6215 | 2021-02-28 08:10:01.976589 | Wendy            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6216 | 2021-02-28 08:49:09.520211 | Barbara          |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6217 | 2021-02-28 08:53:31.673631 | Tammy            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6218 | 2021-02-28 09:07:59.438093 | San              |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6219 | 2021-02-28 09:30:26.966068 | Joan R           |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6220 | 2021-02-28 14:58:11.305224 | Moses            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6221 | 2021-02-28 17:26:51.210201 | De Ana           |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6222 | 2021-02-28 17:27:25.950142 | Faisal           |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6223 | 2021-02-28 19:25:43.374723 | Pauline          |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6224 | 2021-02-28 19:55:34.650488 | Jana             | 159.00 |     6224 |     5757 |
| 6225 | 2021-02-28 20:13:23.158743 | Authentically    |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6226 | 2021-02-28 20:17:04.178635 | J                |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6227 | 2021-02-28 21:49:59.988693 | JACOBINA         |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6228 | 2021-02-28 21:59:00.075468 | Jess             |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6229 | 2021-02-28 22:55:16.655047 | Junie            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
+------+----------------------------+------------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

May just be that I'm confusing myself with the joins perhaps, hoping someone can offer some guidance here.

Thanking you in advance.

- as requested -
  adding the create table for the user_referrals and example output/desired output.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_referrals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `referrer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `isActualReferrer` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );

+------+----------------------------+------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id   | created                    | first_name       | amount | referrer | referrer | referrer | referrer |
+------+----------------------------+------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 6210 | 2021-02-28 04:05:24.937563 | Danielle         |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
| 6211 | 2021-02-28 04:22:35.103951 | Linda            | 159.00 |     6211 |     6155 |     5757 |     29   |
| 6212 | 2021-02-28 04:32:53.045521 | Kathy            |   NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
+------+----------------------------+------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
27 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Here is a demo table of the user_referrals table, with create code + insert demo data

```
CREATE TABLE `user_referrals_demo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `referrer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `isActualReferrer` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );

INSERT INTO user_referrals_demo(referrer,referee) VALUES ('6155','6211'),('5757','6155'),('29','5757'),('24','29');
```

The output should be

UserID | Referer 1 | Referer 2 | Referer 3 | Referer 4
6211 | 6155 | 5757 | 29 | 24

I'm trying to attempt an sql query (I thought I required a sub query) to recursively go through the records to pull the required data.

Comment: [mre] [ask] [help] We can't cut & paste & run and this isn't minimal. PS What do you consider a "sub query portion"? ("subquery" doesn't mean stuff on the right of a JOIN.) Why show a big chunk of code twice? PS Why are you using subqueries & drop columns when you could just use table names? Your scalar subquery could also be a join instead. Research examples of joining. Also join syntax. PS Please format code reasonably. PS LEFT JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON.

Comment: Provide source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Provide desired output which matches this sample data.

Comment: @philipxy - thanks for your input, this is why I'm asking the question, if I knew the answers to what you mentioned there I have no doubt I would be able to resolve my issue on my own. I've only posted this here after spending 6hours+ researching and not being able to work out what I'm doing wrong / how I'm approaching the issue incorrectly.

Comment: In your post you seem to be trying to be asking for a simpler way to write working code. You don't give any other description of what you're trying to do other than the query. What exactly is your problem? What is your question? PS We still can't cut & paste & run, you need to give the input that gave output as code & it needs to be minimal though representative. PS Please address everything mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Ok, I thought I provided enough information or more information but let me try another angle that might help explain it. Had to update the main ticket as I couldn't put the additional information / sql items in the comment.

Comment: You need only MRE creates, updates (in columns), code & results. You don't also need fragments of your real data. Also still it's not clear what the question is. Please read your post. PS Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. See edit help re code blocks & line breaks. PS Adding to something that is not clear doesn't make it clear. Please with every edit make the post the best presentation it can then be.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select u3.referrer as referrer3,
    -> u2.referrer as referrer2,
    -> u1.referrer as referrer1
    -> from user_referrals_demo as u1
    ->
    -> left join user_referrals as u2 ON (u2.referee = u1.referrer)
    -> left join user_referrals as u3 ON (u3.referee = u2.referrer)
    -> left join user_referrals as u4 ON (u4.referee = u3.referrer)
    ->
    -> where u1.referee = '6211';
```

The above sql provided the desired output that was required, with this bit of code, I was able to work it into the parent query.

Ouput

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| referrer3 | referrer2 | referrer1 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        29 |      5757 |      6155 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Appreciate the private messages on this matter that helped me resolve it.